# Draw vertical line for a position in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive

I want draw a line for a position on google maps. e.g. I want draw a vertical line for London city in this location 51.5072° N, 0.1275° W.

I use ionic framework and maps template. How I can draw vertical line for it?
and How I can set current location for displaying?

thank u!

Answer (score 0):

You would like to draw a vertical line from London to what city? You can create a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines) from London to another location.

If you would like to draw a line that is simply vertical, you could just specify another point in the polyline with a different longitude but same latitude as London.

For your second question, I assume that you mean setting the center of the map. Simply call `setCenter(latlng)` on your Map object. Details [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

EDIT:

If you want to set the user's current location as the center, use the `navigator.geolocation` property. Call `map.setCenter()` with the returned latitude and longitude. There is an example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation#DetectingUserLocation).

Comment: my purpose is by user location set map center!